# how to reset class of table's rows after prepending a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am prepending a row every time user adds a new row without refreshing the page. and for resetting the class of rows I am using .each() but its not working properly. Its adding odd class to every new row.

```
$("#tbadver").prepend("<tr id='tr_"+advID+"'>"
    +"<td >"+advName.val()+"</td>"
    +"<td >"+email.val()+"</td>"
    +"<td >"+phone.val()+"</td>"
    +"<td >"+mobile.val()+"</td>"
    +"<td >"+contactName.val()+"</td>"
    +"<td >"+contactEmail.val()+"</td>"
    +"<td >"+contactMobile.val()+"</td>"
    +"</tr>");
jQuery(".tbl-grid tr").each(function(e)
{
    $(e).find("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $(e).find("tr:even").addClass("even");
});
```

Comment: `e` in your code is index not the element. `.each( function(index, Element) )`

Answer (score 2):

You should first reset all table classes :

```
$("tbl-grid tr").removeClass("odd even");
$("tbl-grid tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("tbl-grid tr:even").addClass("even");
```

You don't need to parse all tr with `each`, just parse the dom.

Also, be sure that you're doing that in a "live" event like `on`.

Comment: Good start, but bad use of `removeClass`.

Comment: @ubercooluk It's a bad attitude to edit someone's answers without permission.

Comment: @VisioN I DONT THINK SO..they have the option to approve the edit or reject

Comment: @ubercooluk Yes but you should edit for format things not touching the content.

Comment: @ubercooluk Your level of reputation gives a possibility to make changes without approval. So you should be mature enough not to change the content of the answer, but fix the formatting problems only. If you have another (more correct) solution you should either post your own answer, or give a hint to the author about the problem.

Comment: @VisioN Rollbacked to previous version

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr').removeClass("odd").removeClass("even");
$('table tr:odd').addClass('odd');
$('table tr:even').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Function is not necessary.............

`$(".tbl-grid tr:odd")` selects all the matching 'odd' under `.tbl-grid` rows

`$(".tbl-grid tr:odd").addClass("odd");` is Enough